# How to split string by string length and a separator?

Tags: lua, split

I'm trying to split a string into 2 strings when main string is over 30 chars and separator I wanted to use is a simple space between chars(the last space between words in main string) so it won't cut words. I'm asking you guys for help because I'm not very good with patterns in Lua.

Comment: Please give an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let's say there's a string: "Long string string string string" It's over 30 chars, now script splits the string by last space in the string. So the string would like this:
(line1): Long string string string 
(line2): string

Comment: @nuberelo: Put that in your *question*, not a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
local function split(str, max_line_length)
   local lines = {}
   local line
   str:gsub('(%s*)(%S+)', 
      function(spc, word) 
         if not line or #line + #spc + #word > max_line_length then
            table.insert(lines, line)
            line = word
         else
            line = line..spc..word
         end
      end
   )
   table.insert(lines, line)
   return lines
end

local main_string = 'This is very very very very very very long string'
for _, line in ipairs(split(main_string, 20)) do
   print(line)
end


-- Output
This is very very
very very very very
long string
```

Comment: Egor it still prints everything in one line for me hmm.

Comment: Sorry! works just just fine, I'm new to it so I made a little mistake! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split the string at the last space between words, try this

```
s="How to split string by string length and a separator"
a,b=s:match("(.+) (.+)")
print(s)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Good one, but what it does is it splits string by last space but what I'm trying to make is that it splits by last space that is near at least 20/30 chars. So it doesn't looks like this:

(line1): Long long long string
(line2): string

but more like this:

(line1): Long string string string string
(line2): string and this is the res of the string

Comment: @nuberelo, that requirement was not in the title of the question :-)